# How to use html_select_date (smarty function) two times in same form?

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I am using `html_select_date` smarty function in a form two times. Start date and End date. but this function create a name by itself. I found how to set the ID, is like month_id but I don't know how to set name.

> {html_select_date start_year=1970 month_format="%b" field_order="dmy" field_array="date" prefix="" day_id="edd" class='sd_class' month_id="edm" year_id="edy" year_empty="Year" month_empty="Month" day_empty="Day" time=$edate }

How can I use two `html_select_date` in the same from?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the Solution of this issue. change the field_array parameter value.

now it return date in a array name date. If I change it two sdate for start date and edate for end date it will solve the issue.

> {html_select_date start_year=1970 month_format="%b" field_order="dmy" field_array="sdate" prefix="" day_id="edd" class='sd_class' month_id="edm" year_id="edy"
>   year_empty="Year" month_empty="Month" day_empty="Day" time=$edate }

Answer (score 1):

You could also use prefix="date_widget_1_" and prefix="date_widget_2_"...